# Remove index.php from WP 8.0 install migrated to IIS from Apache (still detecting Apache server)?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, iis, windows

I was developing this WP site using WAMP at work, and now suddenly we're switching it up and putting it on a Windows server (2003). I can tell from the Permalinks Settings page in wp-admin that it still thinks it's still running on Apache, because it gives me code for `.htaccess` instead of `web.config` file.

So I've tried all the fixes I've found around the web, some of them for WP on Windows/IIS still are `.htaccess` fixes, which I don't understand since IIS/Win doesn't use `.htaccess`. I found one solution involving .htaccess but seemed to have a prerequisite of PHP ISAPI, but wasn't very clear about that and I can't figure out how to install it anyway (very unfamiliar with Windows Server). I've tried solutions provided for `web.config`, also to no avail. One resource said to remove `'/index.php'` from the condition `if( ! got_url_rewrite ) { $prefix = '/index.php'; }` in `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`, that didn't work either.

How can I change WP to read the correct/current server type? Just to get WP "on the same page". Then, does anyone maybe have any other suggestions for me to get `index.php` out of the URL?

Comment: Have you deleted/renamed the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: remove your .htaccess file and create a web.config file.  WP should auto detect.

Comment: I was so hopeful... but that didn't work. Still doesn't detect my web.config file and still gives me code for .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

WP has global `$is_iis7` variable, which is filled via following code:

```
$is_iis7 = $is_IIS && intval( substr( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS/' ) + 14 ) ) >= 7;
```

If detection is not working correctly likely something is going wrong with this line, such as server vars not being filled with the info expected.